# Fragment with External AsyncTask and Interface Callback throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, interface, android-asynctask, fragment

I am using ActionBarSherlock to render tabs with viewpager. Each tab has its own fragment.
Also created an external asynctask with callback interface so I can use it multiple times.

Successfully outputting the response but when calling asynctask into fragment, it throws nullpointerexception. I am trying to get reference to a LinearLayout from View and adding more views dynamically to it.
This is my first question on StackOverFlow, please let me know for any additional detail.

LogCat Error :

```
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at in.clairvoyant.comicswala.JustAddedFragment.onTaskComplete(JustAddedFragment.java:78)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at in.clairvoyant.utils.AsyncTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTask.java:54)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at in.clairvoyant.comicswala.FeaturedGridViewAdapter.<init>(FeaturedGridViewAdapter.java:23)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at in.clairvoyant.comicswala.JustAddedFragment.onTaskComplete(JustAddedFragment.java:115)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at in.clairvoyant.utils.AsyncTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTask.java:54)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-01 11:02:00.374: W/System.err(23359):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AsyncTaskClass Below:

```
public class AsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {


    private Context context;
    private AsyncTaskListener<Object> listener;
    private Object mobj;

    String response = "{\"success\":\"true\",\"bannerList\":[{\"bannerId\":1,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":1,\"productContentID\":1},{\"bannerId\":2,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":2,\"productContentID\":2},{\"bannerId\":3,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":2,\"productContentID\":3},{\"bannerId\":4,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":4,\"productContentID\":4}],\"categories\":[{\"catName\":\"Recomended\",\"catType\":1,\"catId\":1,\"productCount\":13,\"products\":[{\"productId\":1,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudharyKaDanda\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":1,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":35,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":10,\"discountPercentage\":50,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":2,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudharyAndRocket\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":1,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":35,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":20,\"discountPercentage\":50,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":2,\"downloads\":12,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":3,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudharyAndRaka\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":1,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":25,\"actualPrice\":50,\"discountedPrice\":25,\"discountPercentage\":50,\"offerName\":\"NewLaunch\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]}]}],\"categories\":[{\"catName\":\"SpecialPackage\",\"catType\":2,\"catId\":2,\"productCount\":19,\"products\":[{\"productId\":20,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":2,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":12,\"actualPrice\":30,\"discountedPrice\":25,\"discountPercentage\":25,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":21,\"productName\":\"PinkiSeries\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":2,\"productSeries\":\"Pinki\",\"units\":5,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":15,\"discountPercentage\":25,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":2,\"downloads\":12,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":22,\"productName\":\"BabluandRocket\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":2,\"productSeries\":\"Bablu\",\"units\":11,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":15,\"discountPercentage\":25,\"offerName\":\"ExclusiveLaunch\",\"offerId\":2,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]}]}]}";

    public AsyncTask(Context context2, Object object,
            AsyncTaskListener<Object> listener) {
        this.context = context2;
        this.mobj = object;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            mobj = gson.fromJson(response, mobj.getClass());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Response in string>>> " + mobj.toString());
        return mobj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        System.out.println("INSIDE POST EXECUTE METHOD>>>>>> "+result.toString() );
        try {

            if(null != listener) {
                listener.onTaskComplete(result);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Listener is Null");
            }

            System.out.println("API response>>" + result.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

JustAddedFragment Class :

```
public class JustAddedFragment extends SherlockFragment implements AsyncTaskListener<Object> {

    // response string temporary
    String response = "{\"success\":\"true\",\"bannerList\":[{\"bannerId\":1,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":1,\"productContentID\":1},{\"bannerId\":2,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":2,\"productContentID\":2},{\"bannerId\":3,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":2,\"productContentID\":3},{\"bannerId\":4,\"bannerURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"bannerContentType\":4,\"productContentID\":4}],\"categories\":[{\"catName\":\"Recomended\",\"catType\":1,\"catId\":1,\"productCount\":13,\"products\":[{\"productId\":1,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudharyKaDanda\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":1,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":35,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":10,\"discountPercentage\":50,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":2,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudharyAndRocket\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":1,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":35,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":20,\"discountPercentage\":50,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":2,\"downloads\":12,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":3,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudharyAndRaka\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":1,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":25,\"actualPrice\":50,\"discountedPrice\":25,\"discountPercentage\":50,\"offerName\":\"NewLaunch\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]}]}],\"categories\":[{\"catName\":\"SpecialPackage\",\"catType\":2,\"catId\":2,\"productCount\":19,\"products\":[{\"productId\":20,\"productName\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":2,\"productSeries\":\"ChachaChoudhary\",\"units\":12,\"actualPrice\":30,\"discountedPrice\":25,\"discountPercentage\":25,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":21,\"productName\":\"PinkiSeries\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":2,\"productSeries\":\"Pinki\",\"units\":5,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":15,\"discountPercentage\":25,\"offerName\":\"Recommended\",\"offerId\":1,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":2,\"downloads\":12,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]},{\"productId\":22,\"productName\":\"BabluandRocket\",\"publishesName\":\"Diamond\",\"productType\":2,\"productSeries\":\"Bablu\",\"units\":11,\"actualPrice\":20,\"discountedPrice\":15,\"discountPercentage\":25,\"offerName\":\"ExclusiveLaunch\",\"offerId\":2,\"imageURL\":\"http://guardianlv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Katrina-Kaif-Is-Dating-Ranbir-Kapoor.jpg\",\"rating\":3,\"downloads\":2,\"language\":1,\"genre\":[{\"genreId\":1},{\"genreId\":2}]}]}]}";
    String jsonString;
    FeaturedGridViewAdapter featuredAdapter;
    LinearLayout justAddedContainer;
    Context context;
    View view, row;
    GridView featuredGridview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_justadded_fragment, container, false);

        // take the parent container where child views to be added
        justAddedContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.just_added_container);
        context = getActivity();
        // inflate the child views (work in a look, lenght will the category count
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, null);

        // reference to gridviews per child
        featuredGridview = (GridView) row.findViewById(R.id.featured_gridview);
        new AsyncTask(context, new FeaturedModel(), new JustAddedFragment()).execute();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void onTaskComplete(Object result) {

        System.out.println("INSIDE TASK COMPLETE METHOD>>>> "
                + result.toString());

        FeaturedModel featuredModel = new FeaturedModel();
        featuredModel = (FeaturedModel) result;
        System.out.println("featured model length>>> "
                + featuredModel.toString());

        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        ArrayList<ProductModel> data = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

        if (featuredModel.isSuccess()) {
            CategoriesModel[] categoriesArray = new CategoriesModel[featuredModel
                    .getCategories().length];
            categoriesArray = featuredModel.getCategories();
            int length1 = categoriesArray.length;
            System.out.println("Length of Category array : " + length1);

            for (int i = 0; i < categoriesArray.length; i++) {

                try {
                    // here getting the nullpointer
                    **justAddedContainer**.addView(row, i, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    RobotoTextView categoryName = (RobotoTextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.featured_title);
                    RobotoTextView seeAll = (RobotoTextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.featured_seeall);
                    categoryName.setText(categoriesArray[i].getCatName());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < categoriesArray.length; i++) {
                ProductModel[] productsArray = new ProductModel[categoriesArray[i]
                        .getProducts().length];
                productsArray = categoriesArray[i].getProducts();

                for (int j = 0; j < productsArray.length; j++) {
                    productModel.setProductName(productsArray[i]
                            .getProductName());
                    productModel.setProductSeries(productsArray[i]
                            .getProductSeries());
                    // productModel.setImageURL(productsArray[i].getImageURL());
                    productModel.setUnits(productsArray[i].getUnits());
                    productModel.setRating(productsArray[i].getRating());
                    productModel.setDownloads(productsArray[i].getDownloads());
                    productModel.setDiscountedPrice(productsArray[i]
                            .getDiscountedPrice());
                    productModel.setActualPrice(productsArray[i]
                            .getActualPrice());
                    productModel.setDiscountPercentage(productsArray[i]
                            .getDiscountPercentage());
                    data.add(productModel);
                    featuredAdapter = new FeaturedGridViewAdapter(context,
                            R.layout.product_view, data);
                    featuredGridview.setAdapter(featuredAdapter);

                }

            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("feature model response is false>>");
        }

    }
}
```

AsyncTaskListener Interface :

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener<Object> {

    public void onTaskComplete(Object result);
}
```

Comment: are you using any list? i think this line mainly cause the problem.  08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
08-01 11:02:00.364: W/System.err(23359):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)

Comment: Please mark out line 78 in JustAddedFragment.java

Comment: new JustAddedFragment() replace it by JustAddedFragment.this

Comment: @Ker p pag - Not using any list, using just an linearlayout in activity_justadded_fragment.xml for adding more views to it. Getting Nullpointerexceptin at line 78 where trying to add views to justAddedContainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new JustAddedFragment() will create a new object, you should replace it by JustAddedFragment.this, this may solve your problem.

```
 Better Approach:
```

you should implement callback interface on your activity, and then move its context to other class, then on completed action your activity would be notify and from activity you can pass your result to fragments.

In fragments by calling getActivity(), you can get activity context and can user for other actions.

Comment: Thanks Anand, I was struggling with it more than 3 days.

Comment: Seems Better, will definitely try.